# What does three dots in a yaml/yml mean

Tags: yaml

New with yaml, so please bare with me.

I am building a azure devops pipeline. And I exported it to yaml file.

It looks like this(removed some tasks/content to make it short)

```
variables:
- name: BuildParameters.RestoreBuildProjects
  value: '**/*.csproj'
- name: BuildParameters.TestProjects
  value: '**/*[Tt]ests/*.csproj'
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - refs/heads/feature/24-Add-unit-tests
name: $(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)
jobs:
- job: Job_1
  displayName: Agent job 1
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-20.04
  steps:
  - checkout: self  
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: Publish Artifact
    condition: succeededOrFailed()
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
      TargetPath: '\\my\share\$(Build.DefinitionName)\$(Build.BuildNumber)'
...
```

I can see three dots(...) in the end.

What do they indicate? End of file? Or some other meaning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Three dots ( “ ... ”) indicate the end of a document without starting a new one

for more details check out this [YAML documentation](https://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#:%7E:text=2.2.-,Structures,%E2%80%9D%20%2D%20%E2%80%9C%20%23%20%E2%80%9D)

Comment: How is `...` different than end of file?

Comment: Three dots means end of document. So below that ... you can start a new yaml document. So in a single file, you can have multiple yaml documents one below another, each separated by three dots(...).

Answer (score 0):

Three dots `...` in YAML are like semicolon `;` in shell/C/Java etc.

A YAML perfectionist starts all his documents with three dashes and ends it with three dots.

Comment: Any other type of perfectionist would use JSON